# Uncaught TypeError: xxx is not a function

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net

I am creating a user control which is a jquery function button. However, I got some troubles when the main page already used jquery function. For example, the following script shows how my control embedded to a asp page.

//Main page

```
...
<script src="/Style/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> 
<script>jquery function for slide show</script>

//<UC:submitBtn ID="sb1" runat="server">...</UC:submitBtn>
...
<div class="slideshow">...</div>
...
//<UC:submitBtn ID="sb2" runat="server">...</UC:submitBtn>
...
```

//My control: UC:submitBtn

```
 <script src="/Style/js/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script> 
<script>jquery function for Button</script>
<asp:Button ID="Btn" runat="server" Text="Submit" OnClick="XXX"><asp:Button>
```

If I insert my control to the position of sb1, the slideshow will work prefect. If it is inserted to the position of sb2, the slideshow will crash and said `Uncaught TypeError: xxx is not a function`

Is it because the jquery has been loaded several times?

Comment: The onlick function have  "()"

Comment: @ankitverma Could you give me more detail about it?

Comment: @MRWonderFuXker look up how to call a function in javascript. Brackets are basic! Your question is very vague with minimal detail. You will get more attention (and better answers) to your questions in general if you elaborate a little more.

Comment: Can you please put your code where you wrote xxx function?

Comment: please add you code..

Answer (score 2):

Consider the following

1. when call a function, you need to call as `xxx()`
2. if you are using the same code, keep it in global. like common script file. And make sure it is properly called in each case.
3. Loading jQuery many time might cause you the error.
4. In the working scenario, check the code execution path then do the same with the scenario which is not working.

You will figure out what causes the issue :)